# Split data in 2 groups in Matlab with both groups having all unique ids

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I am trying to split a data set into 2 groups such that both groups have all unique ids present at least once. The data set is something like

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07
07 05 08 09 10 11 12
01 04 07 13 08 14 15
06 10 11 12 08 01 02
13 14 10 01 07 03 02
15 01 03 04 10 13 11
11 12 03 05 07 14 15
06 05 10 13 01 09 14
```

I am trying to use Matlab to split it in 2 roughly equal groups such that both groups have at least one row where the unique ids (in this case 01 - 15) are present at least once. Will appreciate any help in getting this done.

The data has to be divided in a way that entire row has to belong to either group 1 or group 2. I am looking at my output to be 2 matrices such that

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07
07 05 08 09 10 11 12
01 04 07 13 08 14 15
06 10 11 12 08 01 02
```

and

```
13 14 10 01 07 03 02
15 01 03 04 10 13 11
11 12 03 05 07 14 15
06 05 10 13 01 09 14
```

are the 2 output groups.

01 02 03 04 05 06 07 is row 1. 07 05 08 09 10 11 12 is row 2 and so on. Each row has 7 ids. There are 8 different rows. I want to divide it in 2 groups such that both groups will have 5/4 rows each (minor variations dont matter). Position of ids in each row cant be changed. Each row has to be sent as whole into group 1 or 2 but the row structure (position of each id in that row) has to remain intact. All unique ids need to be present in both groups.

Comment: What if an ID isn't present at least twice? What if the number of data points isn't divisible by 2?

Comment: Also I have no idea what your output criteria means. What is the shape of your output and how does it relate to the input?

Comment: Each ID is present at least twice. I have checked that. Also the output is just 2 groups obtained from the data above.

Comment: "2 groups from the data above" is exactly what you said in the question and doesn't even remotely answer what I asked you.

Comment: Apologies for any confusion. I have edited the question to reflect what I want.

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by "row" because it doesn't make any sense in the context you keep mentioning it in.

Comment: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 is row 1. 07 05 08 09 10 11 12 is row 2 and so on. Each row has 7 ids. There are 8 different rows. I want to divide it in 2 groups such that both groups will have 5/4 rows each (minor variations dont matter). Position of ids in each row cant be changed. Each row has to be sent as whole into group 1 or 2 but the row structure (position of each id in that row) has to remain intact. All unique ids need to be present in both groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

script

```
clear;clc

A = [01 02 03 04 05 06 07;
07 05 08 09 10 11 12;
01 04 07 13 08 14 15;
06 10 11 12 08 01 02;
13 14 10 01 07 03 02;
15 01 03 04 10 13 11;
11 12 03 05 07 14 15;
06 05 10 13 01 09 14];

% find unique elements and rows containing them
UniqElem = unique(A);
NUniqElem = length(UniqElem);
UniqIndex = struct('UniqElem', cell(NUniqElem,1), ...
    'UniqRows', cell(NUniqElem, 1), 'RowCount', cell(NUniqElem, 1));
for ii = 1:NUniqElem
    t1 = UniqElem(ii);
    t2 = find(any(A==t1,2));
    UniqIndex(ii).UniqRows = t2;
    UniqIndex(ii).UniqElem = t1;
    UniqIndex(ii).RowCount = length(t2);
end
clear('t1','t2')

% find all possible combinations to make the first group
Combs1 = testf(UniqIndex);
Combs2 = struct('Combination', Combs1, ...
    'Unique', {true});
for ii = 1:(length(Combs2)-1)
    if Combs2(ii).Unique
        CurrentComb = Combs2(ii).Combination;
        for jj = (ii+1):length(Combs2)
            if Combs2(jj).Unique && ...
                    all(ismember(CurrentComb,Combs2(jj).Combination))
                Combs2(jj).Unique = false;
            end
        end
    end
end
Combs3 = Combs2([Combs2.Unique]);
Combs4 = struct('Grp1', {Combs3.Combination}, 'Grp2', []);
AllRows = 1:size(A,1);
for ii = 1:length(Combs4)
    Combs4(ii).Grp2 = AllRows(~ismember(AllRows, Combs4(ii).Grp1));
end
Combs5 = struct('Grp1', [], 'Grp2', []);
for ii = 1:length(Combs4)
    if all(ismember(UniqElem, unique(A([Combs4(ii).Grp2], :))))
        Combs5(end+1) = Combs4(ii);
    end
end

Combinations = Combs5;
for ii = 1:length(Combinations)
    fprintf('Solution %d of %d \n', ii, length(Combinations))
    CurrentComb = Combinations(ii);
    fprintf('Group 1 \n')
    for jj = 1:length(CurrentComb.Grp1)
        fprintf('R%2d: %s \n', CurrentComb.Grp1(jj), ...
            num2str(A(CurrentComb.Grp1(jj), :), '%-4d') )
    end
    fprintf('Group 2 \n')
    for jj = 1:length(CurrentComb.Grp2)
        fprintf('R%2d: %s \n', CurrentComb.Grp2(jj), ...
            num2str(A(CurrentComb.Grp2(jj), :), '%-4d') )
    end
    fprintf('\n')
end
```

function

```
function Comb = testf(UniqRowIn)
if length(UniqRowIn) == 1
    Comb = num2cell(UniqRowIn.UniqRows)';
else
    t2 = testf(UniqRowIn(2:end));
    t1 = UniqRowIn(1).UniqRows;
    Comb = cell(0);
    for ii = 1:length(t2)
        CurrentComb = t2{ii};
        if isempty(intersect(CurrentComb, t1))
            for jj = 1:length(t1)
                Comb{end+1,1} = sort([CurrentComb, t1(jj)]);
            end
        else
            Comb{end+1,1} = CurrentComb;
        end
    end
end
end
```

output

```
Solution 1 of 12 
Group 1 
Group 2 

Solution 2 of 12 
Group 1 
R 1: 1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
R 2: 7   5   8   9   10  11  12 
R 3: 1   4   7   13  8   14  15 
Group 2 
R 4: 6   10  11  12  8   1   2 
R 5: 13  14  10  1   7   3   2 
R 6: 15  1   3   4   10  13  11 
R 7: 11  12  3   5   7   14  15 
R 8: 6   5   10  13  1   9   14 

Solution 3 of 12 
Group 1 
R 3: 1   4   7   13  8   14  15 
R 4: 6   10  11  12  8   1   2 
R 5: 13  14  10  1   7   3   2 
R 8: 6   5   10  13  1   9   14 
Group 2 
R 1: 1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
R 2: 7   5   8   9   10  11  12 
R 6: 15  1   3   4   10  13  11 
R 7: 11  12  3   5   7   14  15 

Solution 4 of 12 
Group 1 
R 3: 1   4   7   13  8   14  15 
R 4: 6   10  11  12  8   1   2 
R 6: 15  1   3   4   10  13  11 
R 8: 6   5   10  13  1   9   14 
Group 2 
R 1: 1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
R 2: 7   5   8   9   10  11  12 
R 5: 13  14  10  1   7   3   2 
R 7: 11  12  3   5   7   14  15 

Solution 5 of 12 
Group 1 
R 3: 1   4   7   13  8   14  15 
R 4: 6   10  11  12  8   1   2 
R 7: 11  12  3   5   7   14  15 
R 8: 6   5   10  13  1   9   14 
Group 2 
R 1: 1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
R 2: 7   5   8   9   10  11  12 
R 5: 13  14  10  1   7   3   2 
R 6: 15  1   3   4   10  13  11 

Solution 6 of 12 
Group 1 
R 1: 1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
R 3: 1   4   7   13  8   14  15 
R 7: 11  12  3   5   7   14  15 
R 8: 6   5   10  13  1   9   14 
Group 2 
R 2: 7   5   8   9   10  11  12 
R 4: 6   10  11  12  8   1   2 
R 5: 13  14  10  1   7   3   2 
R 6: 15  1   3   4   10  13  11 

Solution 7 of 12 
Group 1 
R 1: 1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
R 2: 7   5   8   9   10  11  12 
R 5: 13  14  10  1   7   3   2 
R 6: 15  1   3   4   10  13  11 
Group 2 
R 3: 1   4   7   13  8   14  15 
R 4: 6   10  11  12  8   1   2 
R 7: 11  12  3   5   7   14  15 
R 8: 6   5   10  13  1   9   14 

Solution 8 of 12 
Group 1 
R 2: 7   5   8   9   10  11  12 
R 4: 6   10  11  12  8   1   2 
R 5: 13  14  10  1   7   3   2 
R 6: 15  1   3   4   10  13  11 
Group 2 
R 1: 1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
R 3: 1   4   7   13  8   14  15 
R 7: 11  12  3   5   7   14  15 
R 8: 6   5   10  13  1   9   14 

Solution 9 of 12 
Group 1 
R 4: 6   10  11  12  8   1   2 
R 5: 13  14  10  1   7   3   2 
R 6: 15  1   3   4   10  13  11 
R 8: 6   5   10  13  1   9   14 
Group 2 
R 1: 1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
R 2: 7   5   8   9   10  11  12 
R 3: 1   4   7   13  8   14  15 
R 7: 11  12  3   5   7   14  15 

Solution 10 of 12 
Group 1 
R 1: 1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
R 2: 7   5   8   9   10  11  12 
R 6: 15  1   3   4   10  13  11 
R 7: 11  12  3   5   7   14  15 
Group 2 
R 3: 1   4   7   13  8   14  15 
R 4: 6   10  11  12  8   1   2 
R 5: 13  14  10  1   7   3   2 
R 8: 6   5   10  13  1   9   14 

Solution 11 of 12 
Group 1 
R 4: 6   10  11  12  8   1   2 
R 6: 15  1   3   4   10  13  11 
R 7: 11  12  3   5   7   14  15 
R 8: 6   5   10  13  1   9   14 
Group 2 
R 1: 1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
R 2: 7   5   8   9   10  11  12 
R 3: 1   4   7   13  8   14  15 
R 5: 13  14  10  1   7   3   2 

Solution 12 of 12 
Group 1 
R 1: 1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
R 2: 7   5   8   9   10  11  12 
R 5: 13  14  10  1   7   3   2 
R 7: 11  12  3   5   7   14  15 
Group 2 
R 3: 1   4   7   13  8   14  15 
R 4: 6   10  11  12  8   1   2 
R 6: 15  1   3   4   10  13  11 
R 8: 6   5   10  13  1   9   14 

>>
```